Disable hardware influence on playwright tests using chromium driver
We use playwright with chromium-driver for our End-to-End tests and now are trying to establish image comparison tests. We fail with fonts getting rendered differently on different platforms, despite using the same chrome-driver. It even makes no difference if rendering using the official docker image mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:1.43.1.
We assume that somehow the host system hardware is involved and causes different results. Hence we tried to exclude the GPU and to force CPU rendering. Either we didn't succeed there or there still is any other difference in the configuration/environment.
The images below clearly show that there is an issue with Anti-Aliasing or Subpixel positioning (is it?) where in one case a multi-color and in the other case a grey-scale technique is used. Canvas rendered font does not show these differences.
The same effect is described here:

Rasterization with anti-aliasing with hinting. Here pixels are forced to fall into integral pixel coordinates whenever possible.
Rasterization with hinting and subpixel rendering for an RGB flat panel display

What option causes this difference?
Can it be unified for all host platforms?

Playwright config:
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: 'tests/specs',
  forbidOnly: CI,
  workers: CI ? 10 : 1,
  retries: CI ? 2 : 0,
  timeout: 60 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 10 * 1000,
  },
  use: {
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    acceptDownloads: true,
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    video: {
      mode: 'retain-on-failure',
      size: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
    },
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    launchOptions: {
      args: [
        // https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
        '--disable-gpu', // Disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch.
        '--disable-gpu-rasterization', // Disable GPU rasterization, i.e. rasterize on the CPU only. Overrides the kEnableGpuRasterization flag.
        '--disable-gpu-compositing', // Prevent the compositor from using its GPU implementation.
        '--disable-font-subpixel-positioning', // Force disables font subpixel positioning. This affects the character glyph sharpness, kerning, hinting and layout.
        '--disable-software-rasterizer', // Disables the use of a 3D software rasterizer. (Necessary to make --disable-gpu work)
        '--ppapi-subpixel-rendering-setting=0', // The enum value of FontRenderParams::subpixel_rendering to be passed to Ppapi processes.
        '--force-device-scale-factor=1', // Overrides the device scale factor for the browser UI and the contents.
        '--force-color-profile=srgb', // Force all monitors to be treated as though they have the specified color profile.
      ],
    },
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Our project',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      },
    },
  ],
  reporter:
    CI ?
      [
        ['list'],
        ['junit', { outputFile: 'test-results/results.xml' }],
        ['html', { open: 'never', outputFolder: 'test-reports' }],
      ]
    : [['list']],
};

Snapshotting and comparison is done by PlayWright:
    await expect(
      locator,
      'Snapshots do not match.',
    ).toHaveScreenshot(`${snapshotId}.png`, {
      threshold: 0,
      maxDiffPixels: 0,
      maxDiffPixelRatio: 0,
    });

(https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots)

1. Rendering result on one Linux PC:



2. Rendering result on another Linux PC:



3. Differences:



How are you comparing the snapshots? Have you checked visual comparisons ? Tried running headless?

@PanagiotisKanavos that is exactly the feature we are using. So image comparison is done by playwright. It spits out the diff image attached. Since the comparison is not an issue (the differences are obvious even without the diff image), the snapshot mechanism shouldn't be the problem, I reckon.

@PanagiotisKanavos Playwright is configured to run the driver headless, as you can see in the mentioned config.

The initial question contained a wall of configuration, no code and doesn't even mention the language or how the screenshots were taken. It still doesn't mention the language but at least one can guess it's Javascript because other language bindings don't have visual snapshots yet.

On top of that, the demand for 0 pixel differences isn't realistic, even with software rendering. Software drivers can easily change from one OS version to the next or even if different patches are applied. Different machines can have different aliasing settings. What happens if you don't use such extreme thresholds?

What happens when you start Chromium or Chrome with those settings when you look at about:gpu ?

We could solve the issue by setting the following additional argument for the chromium driver:
--disable-lcd-text

This disables subpixel antialiasing for LCD screens, which wasn't working on headless environments (without LCD screen) and also depends on what LCD screen you have and how the subpixels are positioned per pixel.
Without the setting chrome seems to use greyscale antialiasing for fonts.
 
(src: https://www.alienryderflex.com/sub_pixel/ )

So you're saying that running tests in headless mode mcr.microsoft.com/playwright on different hardware generates different results?
Any way to reproduce it? I just checked my M2 Macbook and AMD Laptop with the latest docker, 1.48 container - I don't see it. Curios :)
Good you solved it, just interested how to reproduce it

interesting answer!
